# Would the CA benefit of Hidden Sniper grant the effect of Opportunistic Withdrawal?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat-advantage

Would the CA benefit of `Hidden Sniper` grant the effect of `Opportunistic Withdrawal`, even though the benefit is only on your ranged attached?

*Hidden Sniper*

> **Benefit:** If you have partial concealment against a target, you gain combat advantage against it with your ranged attacks.

*Opportunistic Withdrawal*

> **Benefit:** While you are adjacent to an enemy granting combat advantage to you, your movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks from that enemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Opportunistic withdrawal requires combat advantage at the time you are moving. You *only* get CA from Hidden Sniper when you are *making a ranged attack* thus you do not qualify.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that the Cunning Stalker feat is as popular as it is, particularly if you read it to not require you to be adjacent to the target.